# EACCES Permission Denied in Kitkat while writing to SD card

Tags: java, android, file, android-4.4-kitkat

i am trying to copy file to micro sd card from internal storge of mobile and getting error Eacces. I searched alot but now where found clear solution. Is is possible or not to copy in non rooted / rooted Kitkat devices.

Here is my code:

```
package jss.kitkatfile;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button copy;
        copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Copy);
        copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    write();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    public void write()
            throws IOException {
        String dirpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/WhatsApp/Media";
        String filename = "A.mp4";


        File file = new File(dirpath,filename);
        System.out.println(file);


            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] filelength = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];
            fileInputStream.read(filelength);

            //String dest = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Music";
            String dest = "/storage/MicroSD/Android";
            File outfile = new File(dest, filename);
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

            fileOutputStream.write(filelength);

    }
}
```

Error as below:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/MicroSD/Android/A.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
W/System.err:     at jss.kitkatfile.MainActivity.write(MainActivity.java:69)
W/System.err:     at jss.kitkatfile.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:27)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
W/System.err:   ... 15 more
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have arbitrary write access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+.

You are welcome to:

- Use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()` methods on `Context`. If these return 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones are locations on removable storage, unique to your app, where you can read and write.
- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`, and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`. These represent [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) and bring up the equivalent of "open file", "save as", and "open directory" dialogs that you might be used to from desktop operating systems. However, what you get back is a `Uri` representing the selected location, and you would use `ContentResolver` and `DocumentFile` to work with that location.
- On Android 6.0+, you can use the `StorageVolume` APIs to request access to an entire removable storage volume. However, you will still be working with `Uri` values, so this is the equivalent of using `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, where the user chose the root of a removable storage volume.

Answer (score 0):

did you add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

in android manifest file ?

Also it looks like the file /storage/MicroSD/Android/A.mp4.
Are you sure the path is correct and that the file A.mp4 exists ?

Comment: Yes, permissions fo read and write is added. /storage/MicroSD/Android is a path of the android folder in MicroSD card where A.mp4 to be copied.