# Android-Create and Access File Saved to Removable SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-file

I want to test the removable SD card.  I can access the removable SD card and get the available memory with this code:

```
public static long getTotalExternalMemorySize() {
    String secStore = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
    File path = new File(secStore);
    StatFs stat = new StatFs(path.getPath());
    long blockSize = stat.getBlockSizeLong();
    long availableBlocks = stat.getBlockCountLong();
    return availableBlocks * blockSize;
}
```

I now want to save a file to the removable SD card, but I cant seem to get it right.  So far I can save somewhere, but I am not sure where it is saving.  I can't seem to figure out how to access the file created and then test to see if the created file contains the test phrase: "TEST_DATA".

I really need help with figuring out what the path should be for saving to the removable SD card and how I would access the file after saving it.  Please help and thank you!!

To Write and then Read to the External SD card

```
    private void createFileonSDcard() {
        File root = getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(root + "/mnt/sdcard/ext_sd/Android/data/com.example.raptorroboticstest/files/mounted/");
        Log.i(log_tag, "the file_path is " + dir.toString());
        //Gave me the SD Card path
//        String appDirectory = (System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE") == null)
//                ? Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
//                : System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
        Log.e(log_tag, root.toString());
        boolean dirCheck = true;
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dirCheck = dir.mkdirs();
        }
        if (!dirCheck) {
            Log.e(log_tag, "Unable to make root directory and shutting down App");
            exit_function();
        } else {

            File TestFile = new File(dir, "TestFile.txt");

            Log.d(log_tag, "File exists: " + TestFile.exists());

            //Write the Test File
            try {
                FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(TestFile);
                PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(f);
                pw.println("TEST_DATA");
                pw.flush();
                pw.close();
                f.close();
                Log.d(log_tag, "Success writing to the file.");
                final_data = final_data.replace("SD_WRITE|ERROR|FAIL", "SD_WRITE|SUCCESS|PASS");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(log_tag, "File not found Exception.");
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(log_tag, "I/O Exception.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Get the text file
            File file = new File(dir, "TestFile.txt");

            //Read text from file
            StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;

                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(log_tag, "Error reading the file");
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            if (text.toString().contains("SAMPLE_TEXT")) {
                Log.d(log_tag, "Read success");
                final_data = final_data.replace("SD_READ|ERROR|FAIL", "SD_READ|SUCCESS|PASS");
            } else {
                Log.e(log_tag, "Read failed");
            }
            exit_function();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564293/eacces-permission-denied-in-kitkat-while-writing-to-sd-card

Comment: You have wrongly implemented the changes i suggested. Moreover you completely removed your former post where i spent a lot of time to help you. Dont do that. Its not appreciated. You threw away my work too.

Comment: I apologize @greenapps, I had implemented your changes previously, but it still was not working correctly so I completely reworked.  It now creates the file, I am not sure where, but I am not able to read if the file contains the test phrase.  I also implemented your suggestions again, and it says the directory already exists but still creates the file

Comment: The whole `dir.delete()` is nonsense. And again you did not check the return value. After that another mkdirs where again you do not check the return value. This does not look like de code i suggested. Please adapt.

Comment: If the directory already exists it should of course also create the file. I do not understand that you seem to complain about that.

Comment: `if (TestFile.exists()) {             //File exists, delete file
        TestFile.delete();
        Log.i(log_tag, "Deleting file");
    }
    Log.i(log_tag, "File does not exist");
    try {
        Log.i(log_tag, "Creating new file");
        TestFile.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(log_tag, "Exception Creating the File.");
        e.getStackTrace();
    }`. You can happily remove all that code. It is useless. new FileOutputStream will create a new file and delete the old one if there was one. Remove all. You will have better code.

Comment: I put my most recent code up, it does include me checking the return of mkdir() because I was doing that.  It returns the log: Unable to make root directory 2, so I know it doesnt create the file there

Comment: So I should not be worried about checking if the dir exists?  I made sure to check if the return value of the dir.mkdirs();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129943/discussion-between-toby-and-greenapps).

Comment: You are still deleting the dir if it exists. That is nonsense. I just told you today. Remove that code. Adapt your code.

Comment: I repeat: you only have to create the dir if it does not yet exist. If the dir cannot be created you should display a toast telling the user this. And return. Not continue with your code. Now please adapt your code in this way.

Comment: Yes you are checking twice the return value of mkdirs. But exept for logging something you do nothing and just continue with the code. You should return if it is false. Not continue. As what sense does it make trying to create a file in a directory that does not exist?

Comment: I think I implemented your suggestions and I finally see what you mean about deleting the directory if it exists and then recreate it.  Also, if it is not able to make the directory, it shuts the app down.   It saves the file, it says it exists, but I cant find it in the directory.  I guess the program cant either because it cant read it.